# android soundeffectsenabled not working in Scrollview

Tags: android

android soundeffectsenabled not working   in Scrollview  .

I hava a view in ScrollView,but it's soundeffectsenabled not work ,I want to know the reason and how to fix it

Comment: ScrollView has no sound effects.

Comment: The view in n ScrollView  has no sound effects too?

Comment: Views will only make sound effects if they're both clickable and focusable

Comment: I konw it !!!! please try it,what you said  not  works  too .